# KOTH: TNT Run Challenge

Tags: king-of-the-hill

This was inspired by a Minecraft mini-game. The rules are pretty simple: you run and jump around, and every block you step on disappears once you've stepped on it. The goal is to be the last one left.

Your bot should be a complete program. It should accept input as a command line argument. The input will be a map of the "world"; here is an example:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxx x xxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxx1xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx           xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x x xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xx3xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   xx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx      2
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The legend is as follows:

`x: solid block`

`: empty air`

`@: your bot`

`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0: other bots`

Your bot should output your move as a pair of integers. Example: `-1, 2` will move 1 block to the left and 2 blocks down (coordinates origin is in the top left corner).

You may move up to four blocks, manhattan distance, from your current location. If you try to move further than that, the move is invalid. Any move that would move you past the edge will put you on the edge instead. Invalid moves will be ignored.

Once you land on a block it is removed; if you remain on the same block next turn you will fall. Two bots may land on the same block on the same turn and both survive; if this happens, both bots will only see themselves and not the other bot.

If you need to store files for persistence, please do so in a folder with the name of your bot. You may not read other bots' persistent data if any exists.

The match controller is available at https://paste.ee/p/Xf65d.

Please use languages that can be run on a standard Linux or OSX install.

Current results (100 rounds):

```
JumpBot                   31
LookBot                   27
ShyBot                    26
Slow Bot                  15
KnightBot                 2
Moat Builder              0
UpBot                     0
Random Bot                0
```

Comment: Similar, although a key difference here is that you can "jump" several blocks - thus you can't simply block someone in if they see what you're doing.

Comment: you can't close as a dupe in the sandbox and I don't think it is quite one

Comment: Are the moves simultaneous or sequential? Is the input really a newline-containing string as a command line argument?

Comment: I would suggest calling the bot once without a world for initialization (you don't know if your state saved as file is from last round or from this round)

Comment: @feersum moves are simultaneous; the input is indeed a newline-containing command line argument. If you need it as stdin instead, let me know and I could probably modify the contoller to allow for either.

Comment: *"The goal is to be the last one left."* How do any of the bots disappear?

Comment: @flawr if a bot lands on an empty space (or sits on a space for more than one turn) it is removed from the game.

Comment: @bauen1 I check whether there are any spaces on the field yet, because there won't be any on the first round.

Comment: @Skyler could you update the controller? (to include all bots and that i can get the same results as you)

Comment: @bauen1 updated!

Comment: Are additional entries still permitted?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Yes, I will re-run the tournament with any new entries

Answer (score 9):

## Slow Bot (Python)

He moves in a line pattern and checks his moves before making them (also suicides when he's the last one alive to prevent long runtimes)
He won 195/200 Battels in my test tournament.

```
import sys
import re


class vec2(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return vec2(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return vec2(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        return self + other

    def __isub__(self, other):
        return self - other

    def __neg__(self):
        return vec2(-self.x, -self.y)


def xy_to_i(vec=vec2(0, 0)):
    vec -= vec2(1, 1)
    vec.y += (vec.x - vec.x % 32) / 32
    return vec.x + vec.y * 33


def i_to_xy(i=0):
    vec = vec2(0, 0)
    vec.x = i % 33
    vec.y = (i - vec.x) / 32 + 1
    vec.x += 1
    return vec


class World(object):
    def __init__(self, map=''):
        self.map = map

    def getPlayerPosition(self):
        return i_to_xy(re.search('@', self.map).start())

    def getNumOtherBots(self):
        return len(re.findall('([0123456789])', ' ' + self.map + ' '))

    def get_tile(self, vec=vec2(0, 0)):
        i = xy_to_i(vec)
        return self.map[i:i + 1]


world = World(sys.argv[1])
pos = world.getPlayerPosition()


def check_moveV(vecd=vec2(0, 0)):
    try:
        vecn = pos + vecd

        if vecn.x > 32 or vecn.x < 1 or vecn.y > 32 or vecn.y < 1 \
            or abs(vecd.x) + abs(vecd.y) > 4:
            return False

        # Note: this will also avoid positions other bots are on (will disappear in the next step).

        return world.get_tile(vecn) == 'x'
    except:
        raise
        return False


def check_move(x=0, y=0):
    return check_moveV(vec2(x, y))


def run():
    if world.getNumOtherBots() == 0:
        return '0 0'  # Suicide if we are the only one left.

    # this creates the "line" pattern

    if check_move(0, -1):
        return '0 -1'

    if check_move(0, 1):
        return '0 1'

    if check_move(1, 0):
        return '1 0'

    if check_move(1, -1):
        return '1 -1'

    # If we get here, we are desperate and need to find a safe place to jump.

    for dx in range(-2, 2):
        for dy in range(-2, 2):
            if check_move(dx, dy):
                return '%i %i' % (dx, dy)

    # If we can't find a place to jump in close range, try long range.

    for dx in range(-4, 4):
        for dy in range(-4, 4):
            if check_move(dx, dy):
                return '%i %i' % (dx, dy)

    # If we get here, we are dead no matter what; accept our fate.

    return '0 0'


print(run())
```

*I'm not an expert in python and there are probably 100 ways of doing it shorter/better*

Comment: Just one thing, if you are on the same space with another bot and you are the last two, yours will think it is last and suicide.

Comment: when i implement persistency, he will wait 5 rounds until suicide

Comment: Great, that's what I was going to suggest. Excellent answer, by the way.

Answer (score 6):

## JumpBot (C)

Try to jump to field with most possible moves in next round.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct map {
     char *raw_map;
     int size;
     int lines;
     char *pos;
} *MAP;

typedef struct cdata {
     int result;
     MAP m;
     int x;
     int y;
} *CDATA;

typedef struct mdata {
     int x;
     int y;
     int moves;
     int bx;
     int by;
     MAP m;
} *MDATA;

int numberOfMoves(MAP, int, int);
char getAt(MAP, int, int);

int abs(int x)
{
    return x < 0 ? x*-1 : x;
}

void count(void *data, int x, int y)
{
    CDATA d = (CDATA)data;
    char c = getAt(d->m, d->x + x, d->y + y);
    if(c != 'x') return;
    d->result++;
}

void choose(void *data, int x, int y)
{
    MDATA m = (MDATA)data;
    char c = getAt(m->m, m->x + x, m->y + y);
    if(c != 'x') return;
    int moves = numberOfMoves(m->m, m->x+x, m->y+y);
    if(moves > m->moves || (!m->bx && !m->by)) {
        m->moves = moves;
        m->bx = x;
        m->by = y;
    }
}

MAP parse_input(char *input)
{
    MAP m = malloc(sizeof *m);
    if(!m) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to alloc map\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    m->size=0;
    m->lines=1;
    m->pos=0;

    char *temp;
    for(temp = input;*temp;temp++) {
        switch(*temp) {
            case '\n': m->lines++; break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
    m->size = (temp + 1) - (input + m->lines);
    m->raw_map = malloc(m->size);
    if(!m->raw_map) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to alloc raw_map\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    int index = 0;
    for(temp = input; *temp; temp++) {
        if(*temp == '@') m->pos = m->raw_map + index;
        if(*temp != '\n') m->raw_map[index++] = *temp;
    }

    return m;
}

char getAt(MAP m, int x, int y)
{
    return m->raw_map[x + y*(m->size / m->lines)];
}

void posToXY(MAP m, int *x, int *y)
{
    int index = m->pos - m->raw_map;
    int length = m->size / m->lines;
    *x = index % length;
    *y = index / length;
}

typedef void (*DOFUNC)(void *, int, int);
void processMoves(MAP m, int x, int y, DOFUNC proc, void *data)
{
    int length = m->size / m->lines;    
    int left = x>=4 ? 4 : x;
    int right = x + 4 <= length ? 4 : length - (x + 1);
    int up = y >= 4 ? 4 : y;
    int down = y + 4 <= m->lines ? 4 : m->lines - (y + 1);

    for(int i=-left; i<=right; i++) {
        for(int j=-up; j<=down; j++) {
            if((abs(i) + abs(j) <= 4) && (i || j)) (*proc)(data, i, j);
        }
    }
}

int numberOfMoves(MAP m, int x, int y)
{
    struct cdata d;
    d.result = 0;
    d.x = x;
    d.y = y;
    d.m = m;
    processMoves(m, x, y, &count, &d);
    return d.result;
}

void getMove(MAP m, int *x, int *y)
{
    struct mdata d;
    posToXY(m, &d.x, &d.y);
    d.moves = 0;
    d.bx = 0;
    d.by = 0;
    d.m = m;
    processMoves(m, d.x, d.y, &choose, &d);
    *x = d.bx;
    *y = d.by;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "bad number of arguments %d\n", argc);
        return -1;
    }

    MAP m = parse_input(argv[1]);
    int x=0, y=0;
    getMove(m, &x, &y);
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## LookBot (C)

Simple bot that is similar in performance to Slow Bot, except that this one makes random possible moves. Plan to improve this to PredictBot.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define WORLDSZ (32)
#define WORLDSZ_2 (WORLDSZ*WORLDSZ)

int max(int a,int b){return a>b?a:b;}
int min(int a,int b){return a<b?a:b;}

struct Position{
    int x,y;
};
typedef struct Position Position;

struct World{
    Position me;
    double enemymap[WORLDSZ][WORLDSZ]; //chance of enemy present
    bool open[WORLDSZ][WORLDSZ];
};
typedef struct World World;

void world_read(World *world,const char *arg){
    int x,y,i=0;
    for(y=0;y<WORLDSZ;y++,i++){
        for(x=0;x<WORLDSZ;x++,i++){
            if(arg[i]=='@'){world->me.x=x; world->me.y=y;}
            world->enemymap[y][x]=arg[i]>='0'&&arg[i]<='9';
            world->open[y][x]=arg[i]=='x';
        }
    }
}

//returns relative position
Position world_calcmove(World *world){
    const int mex=world->me.x,mey=world->me.y;
    int dx,dy;
    Position poss[40];
    int nposs=0;
    for(dy=max(-mey,-4);dy<=min(WORLDSZ-1-mey,4);dy++){
        const int absdy=abs(dy);
        for(dx=max(-mex,absdy-4);dx<=min(WORLDSZ-1-mex,4-absdy);dx++){
            if(!world->open[mey+dy][mex+dx])continue;
            poss[nposs].x=dx;
            poss[nposs++].y=dy;
        }
    }
    if(nposs==0){
        poss[0].x=poss[0].y=0;
        return poss[0];
    }
    return poss[rand()%nposs];
}

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    if(argc!=2){
        fprintf(stderr,"Call with world!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
    srand(tv.tv_sec*1000000ULL+tv.tv_usec);

    World world;
    world_read(&world,argv[1]);
    Position move=world_calcmove(&world);
    printf("%d %d\n",move.x,move.y);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Moat Builder (Python)

If I dig a moat around myself, nobody outside it can screw me over.

...also known as "Paint yourself into a corner simulator 2016".

```python
import numpy
import sys
import math
import os

if not os.path.exists('./moatbuilder'):
    os.mkdir('./moatbuilder')

raw_field = sys.argv[1]
field = numpy.array([numpy.array(list(i)) for i in raw_field.splitlines()])
field_size = len(field)
x, y = raw_field.replace('\n','').index('@')%field_size, int(raw_field.replace('\n','').index('@')/field_size)
# If there are no holes, it's the first round - reset persistence
if raw_field.count(' ')==0:
    open('./moatbuilder/persistent','w').write('')

def bigmove(target):
    if x < target[0]:
        return min(4, target[0] - x), 0
    elif x > target[0]:
        return max(-4, target[0] - x), 0
    elif y < target[1]:
        return 0, min(4, target[1] - y)
    else:
        return 0, max(-4, target[1] - y)

def smallmove(target):
        if x < target[0]:
        try:
            return min(max(1, list(field[y][x:x+4]).index('x')), target[0] - x), 0
        except:
            return 0, 0
        elif x > target[0]:
        try:
            return max(min(-1, 0-list(reversed(field[y][x-4:x])).index('x')), target[0] - x), 0
        except:
            return 0, 0
        elif y < target[1]:  
        try:
                    return 0, min(max(1, list(field[:,x][y:y+4]).index('x')), target[1] - y)
        except:
            return 0, 0
        else:
        try:
            return 0, max(min(-1, 0-list(reversed(field[:,x][y-4:y])).index('x')), target[1] - y)
        except:
            return 0, 0


try:
    mode = int(open('./moatbuilder/persistent').read())
except:
    mode = 1

# Modes:
# 1 - go to the center
# 2 - go to an outside edge
# 3 - dig moat
if mode==1:
    dx, dy = bigmove((int(field_size/2), int(field_size/2)))
    if dx==0 and dy==0:
        open('./moatbuilder/persistent', 'w').write('2')
        mode = 2
if mode==2:
    dx, dy = bigmove((int(field_size-1), int(field_size/2)))
    if dx==0 and dy==0:
        dy = 1
        open('./moatbuilder/persistent', 'w').write('3')
        mode = 3
elif mode==3:
    direction = max(field_size-x, field_size-y)%2
    if direction == 1:
        if x > y:
            dx, dy = smallmove((y, y))
        else:
            dx, dy = smallmove((x, field_size - 1))
        if dx==0 and dy==0:
            dx = 1
    else:
        if y > x:
            dx, dy = smallmove((x, x))
        else:
            dx, dy = smallmove((field_size - 1, y))
        if dx==0 and dy==0:
            dy = 1

print "%i %i" % (dx, dy)
```

Comment: This actually works out quite nicely, but it will lose against bot that live for a long time (thats why i choose a line pattern btw)

Comment: You might want to fix your indentation in smallmove()... My python doesn't eat this :)

Answer (score 5):

## Monte (Python)

Sorry, that pun just had to be made.

Anyway, this bot works by doing a [Monte Carlo Tree Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search) on all of the possible move sets. Think of JumpBot, only more in-depth.

To run, it needs an extra command line argument (can be specified in the controller). It controls how much time the bot should search for (in ms); I used 750-1500 in testing.

Code:

```
import sys
import math
import copy
#from profilestats import profile
pmap = sys.argv[2].split("\n")
pmap = [list(r) for r in pmap]

#find a player
#@profile
def find(tmap,bot):
   r,c=-1,-1
   for row in range(len(tmap)):
      for col in range(len(tmap[row])):
         if tmap[row][col]==bot:
            r,c=row,col
   return r,c

mer,mec=find(pmap,'@')
bots=[(mer,mec)]

#find all the other players
for b in range(10):
   r,c=find(pmap,str(b))
   if r != -1:
      bots.append((r,c))

#getter function, treats oob as spaces
def get(tmap,r,c):
   if r<0 or r>=len(tmap) or c<0 or c>=len(tmap[r]):
      return ' '
   return tmap[r][c]

#returns manhattan distance between 2 positions  
def dist(r1,c1,r2,c2):
   return abs(r1-r2)+abs(c1-c2)

#gets all possible moves from a map
#@profile 
def moves(tmap,ther=-1,thec=-1):
   if ther==-1: ther,thec = find(tmap,'@')
   pos=[]
   for r in range(-4,5):
      for c in range(-4,5):
         if abs(r)+abs(c)<=4 and get(tmap,ther+r,thec+c)=='x':
            pos.append((r,c))
   return pos


ttlmoves = 40
#monte-carlo tree node
class MCNode:
   def __init__(self):
      self.wins=0
      self.simu=0
      self.chld=[]
      self.cmap=[[]]
      self.prnt=None
      self.r=-1
      self.c=-1
   def add(self, cnode):
      self.chld.append(cnode)
      cnode.prnt = self
   #used to balance exploitation and exploration
   #@profile
   def param(self,cin):
      return self.chld[cin].wins/self.chld[cin].simu\
             + 1.414 * math.sqrt( math.log(self.simu) / \
             self.chld[cin].simu )
   #finds the child with the highest param
   #@profile
   def best(self):
      vals = [self.param(x) for x in range(len(self.chld))]
      binx = 0
      bval = vals[0]
      for x in range(len(vals)):
         if vals[x]>bval:
            binx=x
            bval=vals[x]
      return self.chld[binx]


#update all the parents 
#@profile   
def backprog(leaf):
   par = leaf.prnt
   if not (par is None):
      par.wins+=leaf.wins
      par.simu+=leaf.simu
      backprog(par)

#expand all the moves from a position
#@profile
def expand(rootn):
   ther,thec = rootn.r,rootn.c
   for r,c in moves(rootn.cmap,rootn.r,rootn.c):
      nmap = copy.deepcopy(rootn.cmap)
      nmap[ther+r][thec+c] = '@'
      nmap[ther][thec]=' '
      nnode = MCNode()
      nm = moves(nmap,ther+r,ther+c)
      nnode.wins = len(nm)
      nnode.simu = ttlmoves
      nnode.r=ther+r
      nnode.c=thec+c
      nnode.cmap = nmap
      rootn.add(nnode)
      backprog(nnode)

root = MCNode()
m = moves(pmap,mer,mec)
root.wins = len(m)
root.simu = ttlmoves
root.cmap=copy.deepcopy(pmap)
root.r=mer
root.c=mec
expand(root)

#simulate a bunch of outcomes
import time
curt  = lambda: int(round(time.time() * 1000))
strt = curt()
ttme = int(sys.argv[1])
while curt()-strt < ttme:
   tnode=root
   while tnode.chld:
      tnode=tnode.best()
   expand(tnode)

#choose the most explored one
bnode = max(root.chld,key=lambda n:n.simu)

#output
print("{} {}".format((bnode.c-mec),(bnode.r-mer)))
```

## Trials

25 rounds:

```
MonteBot            14
JumpBot             6
ShyBot              5
LookBot             1
KnightBot           0
SlowBot             0
```

100 rounds:

```
JumpBot             38
MonteBot            36
ShyBot              15
LookBot             14
SlowBot             2
KnightBot           0
```

200 rounds:

```
MonteBot            87
JumpBot             64
LookBot             33
ShyBot              21
SlowBot             5
KnightBot           0
```

All of the simulations above used search time 750. This bot would probably be even better with a longer search time (I don't know what the max allowed is).

### Improvements

This bot still needs improvements in:

1. Performance: it needs the entire time to search.
2. Prediction: it won't account for other bot's moves.
3. Balance: I'm not sure if the UCT formula I am using to calculate which node I should explore is optimal.

Answer (score 4):

## ShyBot (Python)

This bot really doesn't like other bots and will try to keep itself away if possible. ShyBot is also really careful about where it steps; it won't even step on other bots. However, ShyBot still looses often which makes insecure.

```
import sys
map = sys.argv[1]
map = map.split("\n")
map = [list(r) for r in map]

def find(map,bot):
   r,c=-1,-1
   for row in range(len(map)):
      for col in range(len(map[row])):
         if map[row][col]==bot:
            r,c=row,col
   return r,c


mer,mec=find(map,'@')
bots=[(mer,mec)]

for b in range(10):
   r,c=find(map,str(b))
   if r != -1:
      bots.append((r,c))

avg=[0,0]

for b in bots:
   avg[0]+=b[0]
   avg[1]+=b[1]

avg[0] = avg[0]/len(bots)
avg[1] = avg[1]/len(bots)

def get(map,r,c):
   if r<0 or r>=len(map) or c<0 or c>=len(map[r]):
      return ' '
   return map[r][c]
   
def dist(r1,c1,r2,c2):
   return abs(r1-r2)+abs(c1-c2)

pos=[]
for r in range(-4,5):
   for c in range(-4,5):
      if abs(r)+abs(c)<=4 and get(map,mer+r,mec+c)=='x':
         pos.append((r,c))
         
if len(pos)==0:
   bestr,bestc=0,0
else:
   bestr,bestc=pos[0]

for r,c in pos:
   if dist(mer+r,mec+c,avg[0],avg[1])>dist(mer+bestr,mec+bestc,avg[0],avg[1]):
      bestr,bestc=r,c

print(str(bestc)+" "+str(bestr))
```

Answer (score 4):

## KnightBot (Java)

It's works like chess, and is named like Twitch...

...

.........

............................sorry...

```
public class KnightBot{
   private static String[] map;
   private static int myx;
   private static int myy;
   public static void main(String[] args){
      map=args[0].split("\n");
      for(int y=0;y<map.length;y++){
         if(map[y].indexOf("@")!=-1){
            myy = y;
            myx = map[y].indexOf("@");
            break;
         }
      }
      System.out.println(move((int)(Math.random()*4),4));
   }
   public static String move(int dir,int tries){
      if(tries==0)return "0 0";
      int x=dir<2?1:-1;
      int y=dir%2==0?2:-2;
      if((myx+x<0||myx+x>=map[0].length()||myy+y<0||myy+y>=map.length)||map[y+myy].charAt(myx+x)!='x'){
         x=dir<2?2:-2;
         y=dir%2==0?1:-1;
      }
      if((myx+x<0||myx+x>=map[0].length()||myy+y<0||myy+y>=map.length)||map[y+myy].charAt(myx+x)!='x')
         return move(++dir>3?0:dir,tries-1);
      return x+" "+y;
   }
}
```

## SwirlyBot (Java)

These are clearly not the optimal solutions, but I hope will be useful for midlevel testing.

```
public class SwirlyBot{
   private static String[] map;
   private static int myx;
   private static int myy;
   public static void main(String[] args){
      map=args[0].split("\n");
      for(int y=0;y<map.length;y++){
         if(map[y].indexOf("@")!=-1){
            myy = y;
            myx = map[y].indexOf("@");
            break;
         }
      }
      System.out.println(move(0));
   }
   public static String move(int dir){
      switch(dir){
         case 0:
            if(!safe(0,1)){
               if(safe(1,1)){
                  return "1 1";//Down-Right
               }else{
                  if(safe(1,0)){
                     return "1 0";//Right
                  }
               }
            }
            break;
         case 1:
            if(!safe(1,0)){
               if(safe(1,-1)){
                  return "1 -1";//Up-Right
               }else{
                  if(safe(0,-1)){
                     return "0 -1";//Up
                  }
               }
            }
            break;
         case 2:
            if(!safe(0,-1)){
               if(safe(-1,-1)){
                  return "-1 -1";//Up-Left
               }else{
                  if(safe(-1,0)){
                     return "-1 0";//Left
                  }
               }
            }
            break;
         case 3:
            if(!safe(-1,0)){
               if(safe(-1,1)){
                  return "-1 1";//Down-Left
               }else{
                  if(safe(0,1)){
                     return "0 1";//Down
                  }
               }
            }
            break;
         case 4:
            if(safe(0,-1))return "0 -1";
            break;
         case 5:
            if(!safe(0,2)){
               if(safe(1,2)){
                  return "1 2";//Down-Right
               }else{
                  if(safe(2,2)){
                     return "2 2";
                  }else{
                     if(safe(2,1)){
                        return "2 1";
                     }else{
                        if(safe(2,0)){
                           return "2 0";//Right
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
            break;
         case 6:
            if(!safe(2,0)){
               if(safe(2,-1)){
                  return "2 -1";//Up-Right
               }else{
                  if(safe(2,-2)){
                     return "2 -2";
                  }else{
                     if(safe(1,-2)){
                        return "1 -2";
                     }else{
                        if(safe(0,-2)){
                           return "0 -2";//Up
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
            break;
         case 7:
            if(!safe(0,-2)){
               if(safe(-1,-2)){
                  return "-1 -2";//Up-Left
               }else{
                  if(safe(-2,-2)){
                     return "-2 -2";
                  }else{
                     if(safe(-2,-1)){
                        return "-2 -1";
                     }else{
                        if(safe(-2,0)){
                           return "-2 0";//Left
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
            break;
         case 8:
            if(!safe(-2,0)){
               if(safe(-2,1)){
                  return "-2 1";//Down-Left
               }else{
                  if(safe(-2,2)){
                     return "-2 2";
                  }else{
                     if(safe(-1,2)){
                        return "-1 2";
                     }else{
                        if(safe(0,2)){
                           return "0 2";//Down
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
            break;
      }
      if(dir<8)return move(dir+1);
      return "0 -1";
   }
   public static boolean safe(int x, int y){
      return !((myx+x<0||myx+x>=map[0].length()||myy+y<0||myy+y>=map.length)||map[y+myy].charAt(myx+x)!='x');
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

## Random Bot, UpBot

Two starting bots to compete against:

**Random Bot:** An example bot that moves randomly.

```
import random

x = random.randint(-4, 4)
y = random.randint(max(-4, -4 + abs(x)), min(4, 4 - abs(x)))
print x, y
```

**UpBot:** An example bot that moves up.

```
print '0 -1'
```

Comment: I ran 10 test rounds for my (now deleted) Random Walker answer, and hilariously, UpBot is doing very well. He got 7 out of 10 rounds.

Comment: [Here are the test results and test script I used (and hacked)](https://gist.github.com/schas002/27aa722fdc413bf27702629279877664).

Comment: [Here are the full test results](https://github.com/schas002/fluffy-waddle/raw/master/tntrun-results.zip), provided as a zip file.

Comment: UpBot does well because he only moves one block at a time, so it usually takes him longer to run into a wall than it does Random Bot to walk into a hole.

Comment: @zyabin101: you know, you can just run it, hit 'y' for playing a full tournament, and enter 10 for the rounds.

Comment: @Skyler presumably he qanted competition logs as well

Answer (score 1):

## StalkerBot (Python)

Will get as close as possible to the closest bot it sees. Targets Slow Bot's (pointless) automatic suicide. (If I'm on the same square as it and there are no other players, it won't see me and will suicide.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from math import inf
from sys import argv

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    def __neg__(self):
        return Vector(-self.x, -self.y)

    def __abs__(self):
        return self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2  # Technically the square of the magnitude, but we only need it for comparison.

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y

def get_location(grid, target='@'):
    for i, line in enumerate(grid):
        for j, char in enumerate(line):
            if char == target:
                return Vector(i, j)

def main(grid):
    my_location = get_location()

    min_distance = inf
    min_distance_direction = None

    for i in range(10):
        enemy_location = get_location(str(i))

        if enemy_location is not None:
            direction = enemy_location - my_location
            distance = abs(direction)

            if distance < current_min:
                min_distance = distance
                min_distance_direction = direction

            if distance == 1:
                break

    if min_distance_direction is not None:
        return min_distance_direction

    for d in range(1, 5):
        for x in range(-d, d):
            for y in (d - abs(x), abs(x) - d):
                if grid[x][y] == ' ':
                    return x, y

    return 0, 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(*main(argv[1].splitlines()))
```

Comment: Just FYI, in general we don't approve edits that alter code (like the one you did on another answer to this question). I approved that one since it seemed like it didn't touch the logic or anything but just cleaned it up, but that's not gonna fly on most answers. That one could definitely use it though.

Comment: @Riker Understood. It makes sense not to change the logic, but I was having trouble reading that code, so I decided to clean up the formatting.

Comment: No problem, but keep in mind that golfing edits and similar are likely to be rejected on other questions going forward. I agree that the code you did edit was kinda wonky though.

Comment: @Riker Basically, don't make any edits that could affect the score.